# How can I add a backwards slash in a statement without causing an EOF error?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import a text file and separate the data accordingly. However, I need to specify to it to separate based on "\". When I do so, it gives me an EOF error.

I have tried changing the separator to other things to see if that removes the error. It does, but I need to separate based on the "\".

```
data = pd.read_csv("exported_separated_ABC.txt", sep = "\", header = None)

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I would like to separate the entities in the file into their respective columns based on the separator "\"

Answer (score 1):

As I think, you should consider using `"\\"` instead or engaging with python strings such as `r"\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is an escape character in Python.

Try two backslashes in a row:

```
data = pd.read_csv("exported_separated_ABC.txt", sep = "\\", header = None)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I knew it was simple, but I did not know how to search this. The phrase 'escape character' was what I was missing in my search.